# Unity "Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name" using external dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "Shared" project where I share code between my client (unity) and my server (C# server)

Both projects require Newtonsoft.Json.dll

---

When I compile the Shared.dll and put it inside of Unity's Resources folder (so it's included in the build), I get this error :

```
PrecompiledAssemblyException: Multiple precompiled assemblies with the same name Newtonsoft.Json.dll included or the current platform. Only one assembly with the same name is allowed per platform. Assembly paths: 
Assets/Resources/Shared/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
C:/Users/rotmg/Documents/GitHub/AG-LNL/AG-LNL-Client/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0.0-preview/Runtime/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

I realise it's a conflict between Unity's dependency on Newtonsoft.Json and my Shared.dll's.

---

This answer :

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1697304/how-to-resolve-multiple-precompiled-assemblies-err.html

Says to use "merge all the dependencies into one .dll"

So I tried using Costura.Fody to build a single .dll that bundles all dependencies, but then I get an error saying that I should add references to the dependencies that Shared has. (NLog, BouncyCastle, etc.)

---

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: Why don't you just link your shared project against the Newtonsoft.Json.dll that Unity provides?

Comment: The following are namespace : com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json  Each period is a namespace.  So if you have duplicates you must specify the full name of a class object including the namespace.  Normally when there are no duplicates you do not need the namespace.

Comment: @IanKemp, I think that might be the best way to do it, do you want to post an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: for anyone else dealing with this Unity assembly garbage you can use ILRepack to get the desired result, but ymmv depending on what other deps you have.

Answer (score 14):

In my case after updating from Unity 2020.3.8f1 to 2020.3.17f1 and package `com.unity.collab-proxy` from 1.3.9 to 1.7.1 it got dependency `com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json` which was conflicting with my manually imported JsonDotNet package in Assets folder.

[image]

[image]

Removing my manually imported JsonDotNet package from Assets folder helped. After removing close Unity, delete folders `YouProjectFolder\Library\PackageCache` and `YouProjectFolder\Library\ScriptAssemblies` and restart Unity.

[image]

Comment: This is a highly dangerous approach that can break your whole project.

Comment: Note to self: Read comments before executing solution.

Answer (score 5):

based on this answer:
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/juicycleff/flutter-unity-view-widget/414/859018825

best way is to import project without JsonDotNet folder or remove JsonDotNet folder before importing.

[image: JsonDotNet folder]

Answer (score 3):

You have two error messages in the **Console** section indicating the location of each file individually with the same name. Search for one of them (the one you want to remove) and delete it. Unity will recompile the scripts with no errors.

> Search for the file from "Windows Explorer" in Windows or "Finder" in MacOS

Do not listen to others. Most of the answers will make you break your whole project.

Comment: At lease make a backup first. Then you can try whatever method you want

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue after adding another package using Newtonsoft.Json.dll, causing a conflict. For me removing one of the duplicates resolved the issue.